# video player that remembers where you left?

Tags: video

Is there a video player that remembers where you left on each video?
Pretty much like listening to podcasts in iTunes, but with videos.

Comment: If anyone knows some way to keep the playback position with VLC, please answer [Can VLC remember movie position? - Super User](http://superuser.com/q/226397/69039) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [MPlayerX](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mplayerx/id421131143?mt=12). I love it. Not only does it remember video location, but also has seamless fast-forward to the next episode of a season.

Comment: Wow that's a good feature. Even a little piraty